# Modifying 'Time' column in data frame from LAS file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, las

My aim is to take make a data frame from LAS file table. However, due to the time format (hours: minutes: seconds: milliseconds), it falsely reads it and in the end, the data frame is falsely constructed.

```
Here is small piece from my actual LAS file table:

    ~A           TIME           GTDEPTH  GTPQH  GTTQ  GTTN  GTET   GTTVD  
       05:06:54.946.18-Jan-2020 3717.16 -999.25 79.03 1.00   0.00 2797.33
       05:06:55.146.18-Jan-2020 3717.16    0.00 79.03 1.00   0.20 2797.33
       05:06:55.346.18-Jan-2020 3717.16    0.00 79.03 1.00   0.40 2797.33
       05:06:55.546.18-Jan-2020 3717.16 6314.02 79.03 1.00   0.60 2797.33
       05:06:55.746.18-Jan-2020 3717.16 6311.82 79.03 1.00   0.80 2797.33

And here, the data frame constructed by python:
        GTDEPTH  GTPQH       GTTQ     GTTN     GTET  GTTVD  UNKNOWN:1  UNKNOWN:2  UNKNOWN:3
TIME
05:06:      NaN    NaN  -Jan-2020  3717.16  -999.25  79.03        1.0        0.0    2797.33
05:06:      NaN    NaN  -Jan-2020  3717.16     0.00  79.03        1.0        0.2    2797.33
05:06:      NaN    NaN  -Jan-2020  3717.16     0.00  79.03        1.0        0.4    2797.33
05:06:      NaN    NaN  -Jan-2020  3717.16  6314.02  79.03        1.0        0.6    2797.33
05:06:      NaN    NaN  -Jan-2020  3717.16  6311.82  79.03        1.0        0.8    2797.33
```

My aim is to make pandas read the 'Time' column correctly.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import lasio
from datetime import datetime

data = lasio.read('myfile.las')
df = data.df()
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the '.' between time and date.  Since this '.' appears as the 12th character in your time sequence, here is an approach.

```
from dateutil import parser
tx = '05:06:54.946.18-Jan-2020'
datevalue = parser.parse(f'{tx[:12]} {tx[13:]}')
```

For the example this yields:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 18, 5, 6, 54, 946000)
```

You can utilize this technique to convert the Time column to a correct datetime object with:

```
def cnvrtTime(tx):
    return parser.parse(f'{tx[:12]} {tx[13:]}')

df['Time'] = df.apply(lambda row: cnvrtTime(row.Time), axis=1)
```

Comment: I have imported the "parse" library to my code, now I get this error:                           
 TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: I just updated my response, I forgot the parser term in the call